# Multiple lines multiple error bars using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, errorbar

I have three csv files which are read into r as dataframes. I want to create a line plot which graphs the "means" columns and uses  the "sd" column as an above and below error bar.

This code gives me a multiple lines on a plot but with only one error bar:

```
ggplot(data=edge_c_summary,aes(x = times,y=means))+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))+
  geom_line(aes(y=means))+
  geom_line(data = ridge_c_summary,aes(x=times,y=means))+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))+
geom_line(data = valley_c_summary,aes(x=times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))
```

How can I change this code to make each line have the appropriate error bar for each point?

edge_c_summary

```
"","times","means","sd"
"1",1,23.6566108007449,0.97897699678658
"12",2,22.7815144766147,1.15800405896118
"19",3,23.3195763580458,1.10152573531062
"20",4,22.3962138084633,1.25626506966065
"21",5,23.0657328322515,1.17624485082946
"22",6,22.1194877505568,1.32888708114411
"23",7,22.9947511929107,1.25304663407105
"24",8,23.121714922049,1.53918225223541
"25",9,25.9304732720463,2.01279986529601
"2",10,27.2791342952275,2.63979959777048
"3",11,28.7510747185261,2.66804271260005
"4",12,29.4782463928968,3.00223132377325
"5",13,29.7261003070624,2.90440605187483
"6",14,30.3099889012209,3.15106156713522
"7",15,29.4545951486163,2.87696770282654
"8",16,29.1991111111111,2.73260690130748
"9",17,27.6885928961749,2.28949704545011
"10",18,26.8358888888889,1.99002819664902
"11",19,25.4207579378628,1.30543445825041
"13",20,24.6197777777778,1.28917282788259
"14",21,24.4374658469945,1.0001400647698
"15",22,23.7050055617353,1.12314557626891
"16",23,23.9770833333333,0.974658804573153
"17",24,23.2177975528365,1.12526920271045
"18",25,23.5250320924262,1.12891528015421
```

ridge_c_summary

```
"","times","means","sd"
"1",1,23.681434407626,0.989915240381175
"2",10,26.7027079303675,2.32962251222789
"3",11,27.9654291654292,2.38864888176336
"4",12,28.7457528957529,2.69414439432221
"5",13,28.9534165181224,2.68690267338402
"6",14,29.4438223938224,2.91979342111894
"7",15,28.8215325215325,2.6872152195944
"8",16,28.5877813504823,2.57493709806332
"9",17,27.3870056497175,2.19608259108006
"10",18,26.8308927424534,2.03789359897681
"11",19,25.5481404343945,1.41979111451077
"12",2,23.1454838709677,1.13422699496685
"13",20,24.9886246786632,1.36068090029202
"14",21,24.5601606664683,1.05832239119392
"15",22,24.1409646302251,1.16360525517371
"16",23,24.0566369047619,1.00175077418615
"17",24,23.6077813504823,1.11726702939239
"18",25,23.5780952380952,1.10355334756497
"19",3,23.3004172876304,1.10354221988403
"20",4,22.7314193548387,1.23686119466203
"21",5,23.0191654247392,1.18428611015011
"22",6,22.451935483871,1.29021975136401
"23",7,22.9037125037125,1.26259590667806
"24",8,23.1967741935484,1.48879695691969
"25",9,25.306534006534,1.76717581300979
```

valley_c_summary

```
"","times","means","sd"
"1",1,23.6594671201814,1.00814940817697
"2",10,26.0565511411665,2.16929556678063
"3",11,27.7657114295235,2.35397972988285
"4",12,28.3993260320135,2.71926477093656
"5",13,28.8432522492503,2.59319788793986
"6",14,29.1439865433137,2.86403883310426
"7",15,28.7382333333333,2.61080581070595
"8",16,28.488161209068,2.54623846359401
"9",17,27.2384794931644,2.06859192137737
"10",18,26.7695542472666,1.97980925001807
"11",19,25.4289052069426,1.36213237635363
"12",2,23.234375,1.2419107444281
"13",20,25.0288607594937,1.58285604050205
"14",21,24.5043071786311,1.02557712012499
"15",22,24.1491983122363,1.22981051413331
"16",23,24.0402003338898,0.981743823579669
"17",24,23.6662173546757,1.19576801398666
"18",25,23.700081300813,1.0898936548588
"19",3,23.3752591106653,1.08538931168628
"20",4,22.8620981387479,1.32723123739125
"21",5,23.1140421263791,1.16174678633048
"22",6,22.5889264581572,1.39010429942654
"23",7,22.9904,1.22621465254853
"24",8,23.0340371621622,1.48447539690888
"25",9,25.0078692897633,1.60606487763767
```

Comment: Are the first 2 columns in your `edge_c_summary` swapped around? Compared with the other two datasets, looks like `times` and row numbers may be switched.

Comment: It looks as though the other two were just sorted and edge_c_summary was not for some reason. I think I just sorted the others at some point and left that one out for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
edge_c_summary <- read.csv(file="edge_c_summary.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
ridge_c_summary <- read.csv(file="ridge_c_summary.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
valley_c_summary <- read.csv(file="valley_c_summary.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

I also added different colors so they are somewhat distinguishable, that you can also ignore if you don't like them.

```
  ggplot(data=edge_c_summary,aes(x = times,y=means))+
     geom_errorbar(data=edge_c_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))+
     geom_line(aes(y=means))+
     geom_line(data = ridge_c_summary,aes(x=times,y=means),colour="red")+
     geom_errorbar(data=ridge_c_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="red")+
     geom_line(data = valley_c_summary,aes(x=times,y=means),colour="blue")+
     geom_errorbar(data=valley_c_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: your code returns:
    "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'means' not found"

Comment: I added the read.csv commands, as that's they way it worked for me.

Comment: curious...I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: ... added the plot too.

Comment: I had rerun a portion of my code that changed column names- hence R wasn't able to recognize  "means"

Comment: @tatxif, Is there any possibility to combine all the above data into one data and do separate error bars as it is given in the graph, i.e different multiple error bars in the same graph from one data? I would appreciate for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution is to add an extra column to each data frame for grouping. For example, using `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)
edge_c_summary %>%
  mutate(source = "edge_c") %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(ridge_c_summary, source = "ridge_c")) %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(valley_c_summary, source = "valley_c")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(times, means) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = source, group = source)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = means - sd, ymax = means + sd, color = source))
```

Comment: yes, neilfws, that's the way ggplot2 is meant to be used. Long-format data. Also, with this format, you can `position_dodge` the points & errorbars to aid visibility.